# Difference between Probability and Effects in Logit Models

Tags: probability, logistic, percentage, odds, effects

when I run a logistic model I  get log odds that I can easily convert to probabilities. What I don't understand is how can I use percentages instead?

Here's the code:

```
testmodel <- glm(survived ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=Titanic)
odds <- exp(coef(testmodel))
prob <- odds / (1 + odds)
```

If I use the allEffects package instead I get percentage probabilities that do not seem to match the probabilities I calculate from log odds, what is the difference? How can I calculate by hands the percentage probabilities?

Here the results fron the coefficient to probability and fron the allEffects package.

With calculated probabilities:

```
prob
      (Intercept)           sexmale               age passengerClass2nd passengerClass3rd 
       0.97130936        0.07600942        0.49140254        0.21745326        0.09198290
```

With allEffects:

```
library(effects)
> allEffects(testmodel)
 model: survived ~ sex + age + passengerClass

 sex effect
sex
   female      male 
0.7461460 0.1947113 

 age effect
age
       0.2         20         40         60         80 
0.62894422 0.46175092 0.30129044 0.17813638 0.09824401 

 passengerClass effect
passengerClass
      1st       2nd       3rd 
0.7156659 0.4115633 0.2031702
```

I hope I was clear about my doubt.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

In logistic regression you model the log-odds of the probability that an observation belongs to one of two categories using a linear model.

You can use this model to estimate the log-odds given a set of observations of your predictors and you can transform these estimated log odds to probabilities.

But this does not imply that you can transform the coefficients of your linear regression of the log odds individually using the logit formula and get probabilities.

Your transformed coefficients cannot be interpreted as probabilities as you suggest and the effects provided by the allEffects function aren't probabilities either. Effects often measure the marginal impact of an one unit increment of one predictor on the estimated log odds and hence on the probabilities while keepong all ither predictors fixed.

The output from allEffects are not effects in the usual sense. For more information see Noah's answer. Thank you for clarifying this.

I suggest that you revisit some resources on logistic regression. See for example

https://www.geo.fu-berlin.de/en/v/soga-r/Basics-of-statistics/Logistic-Regression/Logistic-Regression-in-R---An-Example/index.html

Answer (score 4):

I think you have some misunderstand about what the coefficients in logistic regression mean. See Chris's answer for more on that. I'll explain what `effects` does. The documentation is (in my opinion) not very clear.

`allEffects()` calculates what are sometimes called "average adjusted predictions". For a specific variable, it sets the value of that variable to a single value for everyone in the dataset. For example, it takes the variable `sex` and sets everyone in the dataset to have a value of `female`. Then it generates predicted probabilities from this new modified dataset. Then it computes the average of these predicted probabilities. This is the value reported under `sex` `female`. The other values are produced analogously. So it's not really right to call these "effects"; they are adjust predictions. It also doesn't always make sense to compute this quantity; its interpretation is most useful when you can imagine manipulating the variable of interest, which you can't for things like sex or age.

To calculate this quantity yourself, you can do the following:

```r
#Get predictions setting `sex` to `Female` for everyone
p <- predict(testmodel, newdata = transform(Titanic, sex = "female"),
             type = "response")

#Compute the average
mean(p)
```

You can do this with the other variables to get the corresponding quantities.

The reason you can't just convert the exponentiated coefficients to probabilities is that the exponentiated coefficients are not odds. They are odds *ratios* (except the intercept, which is an odds). There is no way to convert odds ratios to changes in probability because the same odds ratio can correspond to different changes in probability depending on what the probabilities are being changed from.

Comment: Thank you maybe I can get some clarity thanks to your intervention